# Why cant I draw a rectangle with fillPolygon()

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I am learning Java graphics. I am trying to draw simple figures. However I noticed that the following code won't draw properly:

```
public class Draw extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int[] xpoints = new int[] { 20, 50, 80 };
        int[] ypoints = new int[] { 40, 10, 40 };

        g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, 3);

        int[] recXp = new int[] { 20, 80, 20, 80 };
        int[] recYp = new int[] { 50, 60, 50, 60 };

        g.fillPolygon(recXp, recYp, 4);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Draw panel = new Draw();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);

    }
}
```

In order to achieve what I want I have to use

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Draw extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int[] xpoints = new int[] { 20, 50, 80 };
        int[] ypoints = new int[] { 40, 10, 40 };

        g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, 3);

        g.fillRect(20, 50, 60, 10);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Draw panel = new Draw();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);

    }
}
```

Why is this happening? Am I missing something? Sorry if this is a trivial question, I am just trying to understand Java better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int[] recXp = new int[] { 20, 80, 20, 80 };
    int[] recYp = new int[] { 50, 60, 50, 60 };
```

You only have two sets of points.

You need 4 different sets of point. One for each corner of the Rectangle.

Something like:

1. top/left (20, 50)
2. top/right (x is different from above, y is the same)
3. bottom/right (x is same as above, y is different.
4. bottom/left (x is same as first, y is save as above)

Comment: I changed it to 
  int[] recXp = new int[] { 20, 80, 80, 20 };
  int[] recYp = new int[] { 50, 50, 60, 60 };
and its displaying properly, sorry for the stupid question :)

Comment: @moe, agree with c0der, Sometimes the usage of a method will confuse us. You created a nice simple [mcve] to test the method showing what you tried. We are glad to help when you make this effort.